# How to check if Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql object is connected to a database

Tags: php, database-connection, zend-db, zend-framework

Am developing a Zend application where i need to keep a single instance of the database object and reconnect if the current instance is somehow disconnected. Here is the code:

```
class Resource_PdoMysql extends Zend_Application_Resource_ResourceAbstract
{
    const KEY = 'PDO_MYSQL';

   private static function connect()
   {
        $connParams = array("host" => host,
        "port" => 'port',
        "username" => 'username',
        "password" => 'password',
        "dbname" => 'dbname');
        $db = new Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql($connParams);
        return $db;
    }
    public static function getConnection()
    {
         if (!Zend_Registry::isRegistered(self::KEY)) 
         {
               $db = self::connect();
               Zend_Registry::set(self::KEY, $db);
         }

         return Zend_Registry::get(self::KEY);  
    }

    public static function reconnect()
    {
        $db = self::connect();
        Zend_Registry::set(self::KEY, $db);
    }

    public function init()
    {
        return self::getConnection();
    }
```

}

```
Am using $db like this
$db = Resource_PdoMysql::getConnection();
// <Here I need to check if the connection is open before proceeding>
$db->insert('table', $data);
```

Comment: try running something simple, like `select 1`. If that doesn't error out, then the connection's open.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [`Zend_Db_Adapter` documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.adapter.html#zend.db.adapter.connecting.getconnection), you might catch an exception after calling the adapter `getConnection()` method. This is the copy-pasted excerpt from the example:

```
try {
    $db = Zend_Db::factory('Pdo_Mysql', $parameters);
    $db->getConnection();
} catch (Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception $e) {
    // perhaps a failed login credential, or perhaps the RDBMS is not running
} catch (Zend_Exception $e) {
    // perhaps factory() failed to load the specified Adapter class
}
```

Hope that helps,

Comment: Thanks for the comment dinopmi. I really wanted to find out how to detect when a connection is dropped somehow so that I can reconnect. Maybe its done automatically but i just wanted to be sure that am taking the right approach.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder why you need this.

if you're using the standard ZF bootstrapping, the `Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap`  will manage the database connections for you.

If there are no active connection, the `Zend_Db::factory` will create one for you automatically. also, `Zend_Db` won't create another connection if your db settings stays the same and there's already an active `Zend_Db_Adapter` object

you need to have a section in your application.ini with the db connection, and the bootstrap will handle everything for you.

```
resources.db.adapter            = "pdo_mysqli"
resources.db.params.host        = "localhost"
resources.db.params.dbname      = "db"
resources.db.params.username    = "user"
resources.db.params.password    = "pass"
```